# How to convert a mesh model to a curve/surface?

Tags: conversion

So, I am modeling on a ship, and I wanted to know if there is a way, like I "think" I saw in Rhinoceros 3D. I basically want to convert my model from a mesh to a curve/surface/NURBS model or whatever it is called.

Is this possible in Blender? Without having to re-model the entire thing?

Kind Regards

Skull Kid

Comment: i'm not sure what you want to do, but maybe with wireframe modifier is what you need?
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/wireframe.html

Comment: I may not be very good at explaining either. But, I would basically want to turn my model into a NURBS model, from my current mesh model. In other words, convert to a NURBS (or, curve as it says in Blender) But when I try that, Blender crashes.

Comment: There is no way to currently do this in Blender, actually conversion from mesh to NURBS is actually quite complex to achieve and  not very common even in specialized software. On top of that add the fact that Blender's NURBS engine is quite rudimentary and lacking in features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Blender 2.79 you may consider 'shrink wrapping' a NURBs surface to your mesh.

Add a NURBS Surface into your scene above or beside a meshed object of interest (your ship hull) when in object mode. Select the NURB surface and go into Edit Mode, then subdivide as needed to get a suitable resolution for your needs, and perhaps scaling so that the NURBs surface would fully cover your mesh when shrink wrapped. Return to object mode and apply an object modifier in the deform category called Shrinkwrap. Choose the project option with a suitable direction until you get the NURBs surface to fully project on your mesh.

You could apply the result if needed so that the NURB surface retains the ship hull shape for export by pressing the Apply button in the object modifier interface. You could safely delete the ship mesh and the NURB would retain the hull shape.

- Ed -

Comment: This was a brilliant solution! I'm sorry for not answering sooner, as I now realize I am three years late.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is theoretically possible.

With selected mesh hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then select *Curve from Mesh/Text.*

[image: frst]

Practically thou it's unusable with meshes. Suzanne looks  like this after conversion:

[image: second]

You can't convert Cube, Torus, Sphere etc.

I was searching a while ago why is that but only thing in general is that in Blender modeling with NURBS is... Just is. It's not such advanced or convenient as in other 3D software and it's not recommended as main modeling method.

Comment: I see. Well, it seemed to me like Rhino could do it. So, I will have to re-model the entire ship? Is there really no way I can convert to a curve from a mesh? If no, are there any other programs that can accomplish this task? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SkullKid First of all, may I ask why you want to convert it to curves/NURBS? Modeling with NURBS in Blender is really painful, that's why I'm asking.

I don't know any other software to do it, I'm purely Blender user. I've found only this: http://www.resurf3d.com/products.htm

Could you upload image of this mesh? Maybe I can help in another way.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question seems weird. I was just curious if it was possible. As I haven't found any answer elsewhere, I was looking to see if I could find one here. But my mesh will probably be payware, and it's far from finished. Anyway, I think you've answered my question. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: A screenshot of the mesh: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aor67FEekLdyhJIe3TGKayyFNzvLxw And a "wireframe" one: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aor67FEekLdyhJIfPdSDTG-zjMMmNA

Comment: I've got one final question: Can I, from scratch, model in curves? I mean, to achieve the result seen in my images?

Comment: If you want to convert body of the ship to NURBS it's really not a good idea in Blender. Just take NURBS surface for a spin trying to create anything and you will know what I'm talking about. You can model it that way but it will be simply harder. Look at this: http://imgur.com/a/0pdGD It's really fast try (I don't know how sharp creases should be) with such simple topology with SubSurf, Mirror modifier and Mean Creases.

Comment: And lastly, If you want to sell it later, proper topology would be very important factor. Clean, quad topology is considered by many as the best (smoothing options, modifications, animations etc.).

Comment: Thanks Luke. I do appreciate your input on this subject! As I am certainly not a veteran in Blender (started using it more heavily 2016...) but I have been using 3ds Max since 2006, until 2016, when I switched over to Blender. :)

Comment: you can do a wireframe modifier. Then convert the wireframe to curves, as explained in LukeD's answer, or just leave as a wireframe...