# Convert a Normal Curve to NURB with less control points/Curve points

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, nurbs-surface

I have a Human spine cross section image and I am trying to develop it's 2D surface model in blender as I feel its more flexible than CAD design software( Solid Works, Solid Edge etc).

I have data table of around 12000 points (X and Y). How can I create a NURB curve minimizing the number of Control/Curve points. The reason why I cant go with the Bezier is the flexibility NURBS offers and the end goal is to model the complete spine of human and analyze for stresses and strains.

Comment: It is unclear what your input image looks like and the data table you mentioned. As nurbs is involved it needs custom python scripting. does https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72754/how-to-convert-a-mesh-model-to-a-curve-surface help?

Comment: Is [this](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Curve/Curve_Simplify) what you are looking for?